# Finding parametrisation of curve with the gradient given

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function, i.e the directional derivatives exists and are continuous.
Let $\vec{a}$ be a point in the non-empty regular level set $f=c$. How does one prove that for every vector $\vec{v}$ such that $\langle\nabla f, \vec{v}\rangle=0$, there is a
$\mathcal{C}^1$ path $\vec{r}:(-1, 1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $f(\vec{r}(t))=c$ for every $t$, $\vec{r}(0)=\vec{a}$ and ${\vec{r}}'(0)=\vec{v}$.

So, what we basically have is a level set, a point in the level set, and the tangent vector at that point. We need to parametrize a curve passing through the point with the given tangent vector at that point. Can anyone tell how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). Since $\nabla f(a)\neq \vec 0$ (regularity assumption), some of the partial defivatives must be nonzero. Without loss of genenerality let's assume that $\partial f/\partial x_n(a)\neq 0$. Let $a=(p,q)$, $p\in \Bbb R^{n-1},\ q\in\Bbb R$.

Then there exists an open $U\subset \Bbb R^{n-1}$ and a $\mathcal C^1$ function $g\colon U\to \Bbb R$ such that $p\in U$, $g(p)=q$ and $f(x,g(x))=c$ for all $x\in U$. (The theorem gives as a bit more but we'll don't use it).

Now let's define $\sigma\colon U\to \Bbb R^{n}$ by the formula $\sigma(x)=(x,g(x))$. Then $\sigma(p)=(p,g(p))=a$ and $f(\sigma(x))=c$. This is a *parametrization* of the level set $f=c$ locally around $a$.

It's important that $D\sigma(p)$ has full rank, i.e. $\mathrm{rank}(D\sigma(p))=n-1$. This follows from the observation that the matrix $D\sigma(p)$ is a block matrix: identity matrix over a horizontal row $\nabla g(p)$. Precisely,
$$
\sigma\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_{n-1}\\ g(x)\end{bmatrix},\text{ so }
D\sigma\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\ldots&0 \\0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots &0 \\ \vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\0 & 0&0&\ldots&1\\ \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_1}& \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_2}& \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_3}& \ldots&\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_{n-1}}& \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since rank is the size of largest non-vanishing minor, we get $\mathrm{rank}(D\sigma(p))=n-1$.

Now consider any $w=(w_1,\ldots,w_{n-1})\in\Bbb R^{n-1}$ and define the curve $$\tau_w\colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to \Bbb R^n,\quad \tau_w(t) = \sigma(p+t\cdot w)$$
where $\varepsilon$ is such that $B(p,\varepsilon |w|)\subset U$. Then $\tau_w'(0)= D\sigma(p)\cdot w$. We want to prove that we can find such $w\in \Bbb R^{n-1}$ that $\tau_w'(0)=v$.

- The space of solutions $S$ of the linear equation $\nabla f(a)\cdot u=0$, $u\in\Bbb R^n$ is $n-1$ dimensional (regularity assumption).
- Since $f(\sigma(x))$ is constant, $\nabla f(a)\cdot D\sigma(p)=0$. This shows that $n-1$ linearly independent columns of the matrix $D\sigma(p)$ lie in $S$.
- Therefore the columns of $D\sigma(p)$ generate $S$.
- Since $\nabla f(a)\cdot v=0$ (assumption), we have $v\in S$.
- Therefore there exist $w$ such that $\tau_w'(0)= D\sigma(p)\cdot w = v$.

We are almost done. The only problem is that our path $\tau_w$ is defined  not on $(-1,1)$ but on probably shorter intervar $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. This is easy to tackle with. Let's just take any $\mathcal C^1$ function $\rho\colon (-1,1)\to (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ with $\rho'(0)=1$. Then the curve $\tau_w\circ\rho$ satisfies the desired conditions.

Comment: Can you please clearly explain why $D\sigma(p)$ has rank $n-1$?

Comment: @user1061146 I added some explanation.